# Stop ypbind from automatically running

Tags: nis

I want my linux client to stop using nis services. Can someone suggest how to do it. 
Yes, I've already searched on the web, and also on serverfault. 
As I've mentioned a couple of times on su/so/sf, the search facility is almost half as bad the sites themselves are good.

EDIT:
My Distro is Ubuntu 10.04

EDIT2:
How do I turn it back again.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't getting any answers because you aren't providing enough information.  Instead of complaining about the search feature here, perhaps you could have told us what distro.

If it's a RH based distro, use chkconfig

```
chkconfig --del ypbind
```

If it's a Debian based distro use update-rc.d

```
update-rc.d -f ypbind remove
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just stop the service then you will probably have lots of halts as it tries to use NIS I believe.  If you want to remove NIS from being use I believe what you need to do is edit your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file and remove the nis text from it.  Then you also stop the service from starting as Nathan said.